# GKE Deprecated APIs called

Tags: kubernetes, cron, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this warning message from Google Console for my GKE cluster

API clients in your cluster have recently attempted to call APIs that were removed in v1.25 and are no longer available on the cluster.

Deprecated APIs called

API                         User agent Total_calls   (last 30 days)Last called
/apis/batch/v1beta1/cronjobs    v2.2.0  31145   September 22, 2023 at 5:30:00 AM UTC+5:30

but i am not using the v1beta1 anywhere, I am using the batch/v1

checked with:   k get cronjobs -A -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}/{.metadata.name} : {.apiVersion}{"\n"}{end}'

and all the cronjobs api versions are not depricated it seems but warning still continue.

I tried checking the resource version and couldn't find anything which the GKE was calling
/apis/batch/v1beta1/cronjobs

-->kubectl get --raw /apis/batch/v1beta1/cronjobs | jq
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource

Comment: Were you using the v1beta1 API at some point?

Comment: I'm seeing the same notice.  What services are you using - prom-kube prometheus, cert-manager, argo,  helm?  I bet we have the same service in common somewhere.

Comment: Hello @djvs Gari Singh

I was able to fix this issue, in my case I am using kube prometheus stack chart in my cluster and all the api calls was from kube-state-metrics sub chart.

How I find the issue: Enabled the audit logs for GKE in GCP. and in logs I was able to find the call was from the IP of kube-state-mertrics pod

The solution I tried removed the resources that was creating the issue 

in kube prometheus stack values.yaml in the kube-state-metrics section add the collectors: section (you can find it in kube state metrics chart) by removing the depricated API calling resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue, in my case I was using kube prometheus stack chart in my cluster and all the api calls was from `kube-state-metrics` sub chart.

How I find the issue?: Enabled the audit logs for GKE in GCP. and in logs I was able to find the call was from the IP of `kube-state-mertrics` pod

The solution I tried removed the resources that was creating the issue in kube prometheus stack `values.yaml` in the `kube-state-metrics` section add the collectors: section (you can find it in kube state metrics chart) by removing the deprecated API calling resource

eg:

```
kube-state-metrics:
  namespaceOverride: ""
  rbac:
    create: true
  podSecurityPolicy:
    enabled: true
  # podDisruptionBudget:
  #   enable: false
  collectors:
  - certificatesigningrequests
  - configmaps
  - daemonsets
  - deployments
  - endpoints
  - ingresses
  - jobs
  - leases
  - limitranges
  - mutatingwebhookconfigurations
  - namespaces
  - networkpolicies
  - nodes
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  - persistentvolumes
  - pods
  - replicasets
  - replicationcontrollers
  - resourcequotas
  - secrets
  - services
  - statefulsets
  - storageclasses
  - validatingwebhookconfigurations
  - volumeattachments
```

(pdb,psp and cronjob was listerd here)